# What to do with remaining pieces of PROJECT Hextech Crafting loot?

Tags: league-of-legends

Here's what I got in my Hextech Crafting loot:

---

1. 9 PROJECT Cores
2. 2 Augment Cache shards
3. *PROJECT: Zed* Skin shard (Unlockable with 11 Cores)

---

It seems like I cannot earn PROJECT crafting stuff anymore (*the event is over ?*). I only need 2 cores or/and one cache to unlock that skin previously mentioned.

I've heard that those pieces of stuff are going to disappear in November. Does anyone know something about that ? Is there any way to collect more PROJECT Hextech cratfing stuff ?

Comment: Where have you heard that it's going to disappear?

Comment: I think it was on the client itself. I got to confirm that.

Comment: yep it was in the patch notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this post](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/EN2rJVYE-extra-project-cores) from a Riot official employee, you can disenchant the cores for essence (a paltry 2 essence each). There's no plan to use them for anything else.

I've also seen a response from an official Riot employee that the cores will expire on their own in November in order to prevent any future bugs/glitches with the new client, but unfortunately I can't find the post right now as I'm at work. In any case, the cores are now useless and you might as well get the handful of free essence.

Comment: Your link is broken, please update it

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in the URL. Should be fixed now.